# Python pixel manipulation library

Tags: python

So I'm going through the beginning stages of producing a game in Python, and I'm looking for a library that is able to manipulate pixels and blit them relatively fast.

My first thought was pygame, as it deals in pure 2D surfaces, but it only allows pixel access through `pygame.get_at()`, `pygame.set_at()` and `pygame.get_buffer()`, all of which lock the surface each time they're called, making them slow to use. I can also use  the `PixelArray` and `surfarray` classes, but they are locked for the duration of their lifetimes, and the only way to blit them to a surface is to either copy the pixels to a new surface, or use `surfarray.blit_array`, which requires creating a subsurface of the screen and blitting it to that, if the array is smaller than the screen (if it's bigger I can just use a slice of the array, which is no problem).

I don't have much experience with PyOpenGL or Pyglet, but I'm wondering if there is a faster library for doing pixel manipulation in, or if there is a faster method, in Pygame, for doing pixel manupilation. I did some work with SDL and OpenGL in C, and I do like the idea of adding vertex/fragment shaders to my program.

My program will chiefly be dealing in loading images and writing/reading to/from surfaces.

Comment: Are you sure you _really_ need to write pixel per pixel? Doing things like this en masse is _much_ faster.

Comment: The engine will be programmed to be capable of replicating liero/worms type environments, where per pixel manipulation will be essential. There is a way to do it with a bunch vectors, but I like the simple freedom of pixels. This wouldn't be a problem in C, where I already have some experience in doing this kind of thing, but I'd like to program it in Python. Although if I lose some essential capabilities, I will have to resort to C.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm)? You'd still have to communicate the data back to pygame via frombuffer or somesuch to do the blitting, but the PIL can handle the pixel access.

Comment: That might be especially powerful in combination with numpy.
Try this link: http://jehiah.cz/archive/creating-images-with-numpy

Answer (score 0):

I checked out pyglet, and saw that it works well for static per pixel collision, when the image is not manipulated too much; however, I'm not sure how well it works with a dynamic image.

In short, I'm looking for a library that's able to quickly display a buffer of pixels. This buffer will be constantly changing, so fast access and blitting is essential. This could be done in C with relative ease using SDL; however, I'm looking for a similar method in Python. I'm not even too worried about hardware acceleration at this point, although it would certainly be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Python bindings](http://python-sfml.org/) of [Simple and Fast Multimedia Library](http://sfml-dev.org/). From it's [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php):

---

It implements the same 2D drawing and OpenGL-related functions (see their base class [sf::RenderTarget](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php) for more details), the difference is that the result is stored in an off-screen texture rather than being show in a window.

Rendering to a texture can be useful in a variety of situations:

- precomputing a complex static texture (like a level's background from multiple tiles)
- applying post-effects to the whole scene with shaders
- creating a sprite from a 3D object rendered with OpenGL
- etc.

---

Check also methods ***contains*** and ***intersects*** of [sf::Rect< T > Class Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633900/python-pixel-manipulation-library).